# Prime number problem

Tags: prime-numbers

Find positive integers $x,y$ and prime $p$ so that $(xy^3)/(x+y)=p$

Comment: What is the question, and what effort have you made in attempting to answering on your own? (under the assumption that you're asking others to make that effort for you).

Comment: Excuse me! I tried my best to solve the problem in 1 day, but i couldn't. So i posted it on that website because i need people to help me solve it.

Comment: No problem. Can you please share your attempts, thoughts and observations on the problem?

Comment: Oh god. I told you i had tried all solutions i thought to solve it but everything was wrong. And i need someone give me an idea.

Comment: There is no solution with $1\le x,y\le 10^4$

Comment: I don't think that asking for divine intervention is of any use at this point. Please share your observations. For example, what should be the relation between $x$ and $y$ in order for $\frac{(xy)^3}{x+y}$ to be integer?

Comment: Sorry. I wrote wrongly. But i have fixed it

Comment: I would try to use the fact that for the division to produce an integer (let alone a prime number) all prime factors of $x+y$ must be factors of either $x$ or $y$, and hence both. Do you see why?

Comment: @Peter: OP has changed the original expression.

Comment: Oh. It's a good idea

Comment: It's trickier than I thought initially. $x=14$, $y=2$ yields $p=7$, but are there other solutions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Not, if $1\le x,y\le 10^4$

Comment: I think that's all. I have just used pascal software to solve it and the result is the same as yours: x=14,y=2 and p=7. But i don't know how to solve it in math

Comment: By the way, where did you find this problem? It could be a practice problem for a math contest (in which case it could be tagged [tag:contest-math]).

Answer (score 3):

Let's write $d=\gcd(x,y)$, $x=dx_1$, $y=dy_1$ with $\gcd(x_1,y_1)=1$.

**Claim.** $y_1=1$.

**Proof.** Otherwise there exists a prime $\ell\mid y_1$. As $\ell\nmid x_1$ we also have $\ell\nmid (x_1+y_1)$. Let us consider the fraction
$$
\frac{xy^3}{x+y}=\frac{d^4x_1y_1^3}{d(x_1+y_1)}=\frac{d^3x_1y_1^3}{x_1+y_1}.
$$
Here the denominator is not divisible by $\ell$, but the numerator is divisible by $\ell^3$. Therefore $\ell^3\mid p$ which is absurd. QED.

So $d=y$ and $y\mid x$. Let's write $x=zy$. We get
$$
p=\frac{xy^3}{x+y}=\frac{zy^4}{y(z+1)}=\frac{zy^3}{z+1}.
$$
For this to be an integer the numerator must be divisible by $z+1$. As $\gcd(z,z+1)=1$ we must have $z+1\mid y^3$. As $p$ is a prime we have two possibilities:

- A) $z=1$ and $y^3=p(z+1)$
- B) $z=p$ and $y^3=z+1$

The case A is impossible, because then $y^3=2p$. In case B we get $p=y^3-1$.
Because $y-1\mid (y^3-1)$, $p$ can be a prime only if $y=2$.

This leaves $y=2$, $z=7$, $x=14$, $p=7$ as the only solution.

Comment: Woa. Brilliant. Your answer is very nice and clear. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @N.Paul Sorry about initially misleading you with that "hint" in a comment. Well, I managed to mislead myself for a while also :-)

Comment: I am slightly worried that we might have already had this problem in the form $$p=\frac{zy^3}{z+1}.$$ It somehow rings a bell, but I may be confusing it with another question. Couldn't find it anyway :-/

Comment: That problem is in my midterm test. Anyway, your solution you got is right: x=14, y=2, p=7